# Getting value of XML node

Tags: java, xml, dom

I know how to parse XML documents with DOM when they are in the form:

```
<tagname> valueIWant </tagname>
```

However, the element I'm now trying to get is instead in the form

```
<photo farm="9" id="8147664661" isfamily="0" isfriend="0" ispublic="1" 
       owner="8437609@N04" secret="4902a217af" server="8192" title="Rainbow"/>
```

I usually use `cel.getTextContent()` to return the value, but that doesn't work in this case. Neither does `cel.getAttributes()`, which I thought would work...

Ideally, I need to just get the id and owner numerical values. However if someone can help on how to get all of it, then I can deal with removing the parts I don't want later.

Comment: This isn't necessaraly valid format in any particular language, but it reflects how xml generally tends to be structured `string nine = doc.attributes["farm"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking to retrieve is the value of different attributes that are attached with an Element. Look at using the [`getAttribute(String name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) method to achieve this

If you want to retrieve all the attributes, all you can do so using [`getAttributes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getAttributes%28%29) and iterate through it. An example of both of these methods might be something like this:

```
private void getData(Document document){
    if(document == null)
        return;

    NodeList list = document.getElementsByTagName("photo");
    Element photoElement = null;

    if(list.getLength() > 0){
        photoElement = (Element) list.item(0);
    }

    if(photoElement != null){
        System.out.println("ID: "+photoElement.getAttribute("id"));
        System.out.println("Owner: "+photoElement.getAttribute("owner"));

        NamedNodeMap childList = photoElement.getAttributes();
        Attr attribute;

        for(int index = 0; index < childList.getLength(); index++){
            if(childList.item(index).getNodeType() == Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE){
                attribute = ((Attr)childList.item(index));
                System.out.println(attribute.getNodeName()+" : "+attribute.getNodeValue());
            }else{
                System.out.println(childList.item(index).getNodeType());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1766153: Glad to help. I updated my answer to give you an example of how to retrieve particular attribute or all attributes at the same time. Hope this helps as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Element photo = (Element)yournode;
photo.getAttribute("farm");
```

will get you the value of the farm attribute. You need to treat your node as an Element to have access to these attributes ([doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29)).